# How to model data in noSql databases

Tags: mongodb, nosql, couchdb

Hi I am bit confused on the same topic.For example in my scenario .If I am having a user table and one another table for order.I placed an order in nosql database then how should I maintain user info in the order table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @daniele3004 at which rule my question fails ?

Answer (score 7):

SQL and NoSQL are completely different database concepts all together. What we call "tables" in SQL are replaced by "collections", and what we call "rows" in tables are replaced by "documents".

With that concept clearly set in mind, its pretty much easy to understand how NoSQL databases work.

You have CRUD Operations similar to SQL, and you wont have concepts such as Joins, or primary key and foreign key relationship.

Data is stored in the form of JSON/BSON, as in raw javascript objects which are recieved from any form of client.(Be it android or webapp).

So a SQL Table consisting of(for example) :

```
NAME|ADDRESS|AGE|SALARY
ABC |XYZ    |23 |50000
```

in an NoSQL Collection becomes :

```
{
    "NAME":"ABC",
    "ADDRESS":"XYZ",
    "AGE":23,
    "SALARY":50000
}
```

So to answer your question of how to update a username in an order table, you will have to come up with a totally different schema. We use the concept of nested objects here.

In a NoSQL scenario, Your user "collection", will have have the list of orders made by the user as an nested object inside your user collection as a field. So if you update the user name in the user "collection", it is as good as performing an update operation on all the orders that user has made till now.

So your schema might look like(for example) :

```
{
  username:"abc",
  orders:[{
             order_number:1,
             order_name:"abcd"
          },
          {
             order_number:2,
             order_name:"xyza"
          }]
 }
```

Mongodb is the simplest form of NoSQL database you can get. Its a good starting point to deep dive into NoSQL.

For more on how to work with mongodb, look into this : https://docs.mongodb.com/

Comment: Thank you for the clear concept.

Answer (score 3):

At first, the move to NoSQL can be a bit of a challenge, but it's best if you think of your data model as more of an object model.  Not sure what you are using this for, so I'll give you a short answer and a long one.

### Short Answer

Consider putting a sub-set of your user data right inside of the order object:

```
{ OrderId: 123, 
  OrderDate:'2018-08-01', 
  User: {
    Id: 1234, 
    UserName:'Joe Smith', 
    City: 'Chicago',
    (etc)
  }
}
```

You can create another table for "complete" user data (eg - id, name, password, etc), but put *the user data that you'll use in order-related queries* inside of the order itself.

### Long Answer

NoSQL turns some of the core concepts of relational data upside down.  Those differences are what make NoSQL extremely fast.  One of the really big mental hurdles you have to overcome when you make the shift to NoSQL is the concept of "denormalization."

There are a couple of really great articles out there on [NoSQL data models](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and on [denormalizing data](https://medium.com/@pmuens/why-we-don-t-denormalize-anymore-dc58b898765c) and rethinking the idea of a [one to many](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2339664&seqNum=4) relationship using embedded docs and [one-to-several](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/designing-one-many-relations-mongodb-vs-mysql/) relationships.

In general, most NoSQL implementations are not great with joins.  So, we typically end up doing "join-like" work in the application tier, not the db tier to keep the system moving at lightning speed.

There is A LOT more to it (eg - patterns for updating denormalized data), but that's the gist of your question.  Try embedding just enough of the user object inside of the order object to fulfill 90% of your order query needs.  Then, store the "complete" user data in the user table.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Make some concepts clear to me.But if user change its name then should i need to update the order table like `UserName`

Comment: Yep - and great example.  Rare that a user would change their name, but it happens (marriage, divorce, etc).  We kick off that update as a background process when we "save" the user object.  This way, the "user" object is responsible for maintaining consistency.  Some people schedule de-normalization "cleanup" routines instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your data model for the order table to take in user table values. You can pull the current user, and push their info with the order into the order table. If there is no current user, you can create a query to pull the user data from the user table, and push that into the order table along with the order data.

Comment: ok Once i saved the user detail into the order table .No Issue.But what if user editted his profie then how can i identify that who placed this order ? @K-Crane